# When I run a program in debug mode in vs-2010, sometimes after the build is complete, there is a long delay before the program starts. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

*Sometimes* I get an annoying problem. When I try to start the program in debug mode (F5), The build completes relatively quickly, but then vs-2010 just sits there for like 10-15 seconds in between the completion of the build and when the program starts. The mouse cursor turns to that vista waiting circle (Running windows 7 though).

It also *sometimes* takes quite some time to STOP the debug mode and get back to visual studio editing mode, or whatever the normal mode of it is called.

Has anyone else had this problem? What could be the cause of it?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I deleted the bin and obj directories of my project directory.

Some file in there must have been the culprit.

Anyone have a clue what might have went wrong?

Comment: This problem also eventually affects my I7 machine with 12 gigs of ram.  The solution for me is to do a fresh checkout from the repository, thereby eliminating all the bin and obj folders since I don't version them. Needs to be done every once in awhile, no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

There are several factors that could affect it.

One of the delays is casued due to JIT compilation.

In debug mode, none of the optimizations are in place. Due to the full debug info being project, the resulting assembly is also bigger and hence will take time to load in memory.

Then if you're running a web app, spinning up webserver might also take time. If you're a console app, then loading relevant assemblies will take some time.

If you've virus scann scanning all files, that'll slow down the file access time and subsequently startup time.

**Edit:** As you mentioned in your comments, having powerful hardware will help in speedy execution obviously but do understand that there is this extra processing that needs to happen.

A *workaround* is to start in non-debug mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and then attach to process later.

Comment: It takes about an equal amount of time to attach the process in your workaround as the delay i'm describing.

Comment: Well, at least your startup will be faster, doesn't it? You've to spend that amount of time anyway coz all that processing needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is Vista?

How much RAM do you have?

Comment: running 7, just referred to the circle as vista since that's when it first appeared.

Comment: Only 2GB of RAM. Maybe that's the trouble. My powerful computer never has this problem

Answer (score 1):

2GB of ram might be why. I am using a Windows XP box with 2GBs of RAM and I have a slight delay and I know the windows manager for Win7 uses more RAM than XP does

Answer (score 1):

Also check the number of breakpoints you have set up. I've seen debuggers crap out when there are too many break points.

Just use enough for the current task.